# select managers with 2 employees

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
EMPNO   ENAME   JOB         MGR
7369    SMITH   CLERK       7902
7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN    7698
7521    WARD    SALESMAN    7698
7566    JONES   MANAGER     7839
7654    MARTIN  SALESMAN    7698
7698    BLAKE   MANAGER     7839
7782    CLARK   MANAGER     7839
7788    SCOTT   ANALYST     7566
7839    KING    PRESIDENT   null
7844    TURNER  SALESMAN    7698
7876    ADAMS   CLERK       7788
7900    JAMES   CLERK       7698
7902    FORD    ANALYST     7566
7934    MILLER  CLERK       7782
```

I need to select all managers with 2 employees only (empl. MGR field has to be equal to MANAGER's EMPNO)

Can I do it with PARTITION or other OLAP function?

Comment: please post your attempt at solving this

Comment: Check out GROUP BY and HAVING and COUNT.

Comment: Smells like homework...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I do it with PARTITION

Sure. Analytics would certainly do it. Use **COUNT() OVER()**.

For example, using standard EMP table in SCOTT schema:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT e.*, count(empno) OVER(PARTITION BY mgr ORDER BY NULL) cnt
  3  FROM emp e
  4  )
  5  SELECT empno, ename, mgr
  6  FROM DATA
  7  WHERE cnt = 2;

     EMPNO ENAME             MGR
---------- ---------- ----------
      7902 FORD             7566
      7788 SCOTT            7566
```

Comment: How can I extract MGR ENAME for this:`SELECT mgr
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT e.MGR, count(empno) OVER(PARTITION BY mgr ORDER BY NULL) cnt FROM emp e)
WHERE cnt = 2;`

Comment: Do you need the name for both manager as well as the employees?

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
SELECT manager_id
FROM employees
GROUP BY manager_id
HAVING count(employee_id)=2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery for that:

```
SELECT * FROM employees e1 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees e2 WHERE e2.MGR = e1.EMPNO) >= 2
```

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM EMP e 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMP m WHERE e.MGR = m.EMPNO) >= 2
; -- I have some error here -- no results

Comment: Sorry - my query gives just EMPTY result - each subquery select gives count =1, don't know where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

managed to do it like this:

```
SELECT data.mgr, d.ENAME
FROM EMP d
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT e.MGR, count(empno) OVER(PARTITION BY mgr ORDER BY NULL) cnt FROM emp e) data 
ON data.mgr = d.EMPNO 
WHERE cnt = 2;
```

is there a better/ nicer or shorter way?

Comment: At least you don't need DISTINCT in your subquery

Comment: If I delete distinct, I will have doubled rows, I can delete "ORDER BY NULL"